Java Implementations to Print a String n Times
Why do the first two Java implementations to print the string 'n' times result in a stack overflow error when 'n' is large (e.g., 10^4), whereas the third implementation does not encounter this issue?
First Snippet -
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Solution {

    static void print(int count, ArrayList<String> list){
        if(count < 1){
            return;
        }
        list.add("Coding Ninjas" + " ");
        count--;
        print(count, list);
    }
    public static List<String> printNtimes(int n){
        // Write your code here.
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        print(n, list);
        return list;
    }
}

Second Snippet -
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Solution {

    static List<String> print(int count, ArrayList<String> list){
        if(count == 0){
            return list;
        }
        list.add("Coding Ninjas" + " ");
        count--;
        return print(count, list);
    }
    public static List<String> printNtimes(int n){
        // Write your code here.
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        return print(n, list);
    }
}

Third Snippet -
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Solution {

    static List<String> print(List<String> list, String str, int n){
        if(n == 0){
            return list;
        }
        list.add(str);
        return print(list, str, n - 1);
    }
    public static List<String> printNtimes(int n){
        // Write your code here.
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String str = "Coding Ninjas ";
        return print(list, str, n);
    }
}   

I'm not able to figure out why this is happening because all of the three different codes are doing the same thing. I'm trying to solve this problem with O(n) Time Complexity. Anyone can help me to figure out why the third snippet is not giving the stackoverflow error ?

@Martheen I'm a beginner and I don't think I can understand it easily. Could you please provide another solution?

It looks like changing ArrayList to List in declaration of print method like static void print(int count, ArrayList<String> list) to static void print(int count, List<String> list) solved the problem (at least for 10_000 calls). Interesting mechanism. May be worth asking separate question about that specifically.

Here I refactored Solutions 3 and 1 to make my explanation much understandable :
Refactored Solution 1
public class Solution1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = printNtimes(100000);
    }

    public static List<String> printNtimes(int n) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        print(list, n);
        return list;
    }

    static void print(ArrayList<String> list, int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return;
        }
        list.add("Coding Ninjas" + " ");
        n--;
        System.out.println(n + "-)List : " + list.size());
        print(list, n);
    }

}

Output of Solution 1
99999-)List : 1
99998-)List : 2
...
98337-)List : 1663
    at _2_print_string.Solution1.print(Solution1.java:25)
    at _2_print_string.Solution1.print(Solution1.java:25)
...
    at _2_print_string.Solution1.print(Solution1.java:25)
    at _2_print_string.Solution1.print(Solution1.java:25)
98336-)List : 1664
98335-)List : 1665
    ...
    

Refactored Solution 3
 public class Solution3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = printNtimes(10000);
    }

    public static List<String> printNtimes(int n) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        print(list, n);
        return list;
    }

    static List<String> print(List<String> list, int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return list;
        }
        list.add("Coding Ninjas" + " ");
        n--;
        print(list, n);
        System.out.println(n + "-)List : " + list.size());
        return list;
    }

}

Output of Solution 3
0-)List : 10000
1-)List : 10000
2-)List : 10000
3-)List : 10000
    ...
9998-)List : 10000
9999-)List : 10000


 Explanation


I can't give you any documentation but I can say from my experience that if you call the same function repeatedly without doing another process, an error will occur to stop the program to prevent working for infinitive. Because it means that if any function is working for a small process repeatedly then there may have already occured most likely bug. You can think that this is a way to save the computer from working meaningless forever. This kind of data is saved in the queue. And This queue has a limit. If the limit is reached, then programs give the error.
( repeatedly: I don't know the limit but it can be any number such as 10^3 or 10^7 probably changeable)

 What is Queue (in this problem's conversation)?


The queue keeps how many times same function is called. Usually recursive functions have this queue problem. If you only realize same function over and over then queue will get bigger. But when you do another process then queue get reset. If the queue get to max limit, then the error which mentionedyou mention will be occured. To prevent this problem you should reset the queue by doing another processin recursive function.

Problem of Solution 1 and Solution 2


These are just called the print() function and do nothing except reach the last index. This means that in these solutions calling the same print() function makes the queue get bigger and reach to max limit. And then the error occurs.

 Solution 3


This seems almost the same with others but indeed there is a huge difference. The print() function not only calls another print() function but sometimes returns the list. So the queue gets reset. Let me explain in the next example.

 Examples


Let's say you call the print() function for Solutions 1 and 2. 10^4  times function will be called. This is a lot for a queue which adds the same progress.
Let's say you call the same function for Solution 3. After calling repeatedly the print function, it will return the list. Oops. At the moment another process is done, the queue is reset.
Solutions 1 and 2 only reset the queue when the print() function called 1000 + 999+ 998...
total called print function to reset query:  1000+999+...+2+1=500500
Solution 3 reset the queue when the print() function is called 1000 times. Then will reset the queue when the print() function is called 999 times.
total called print function to reset the queue: 1000,
total called print function to reset the queue: 999,
...

 Shortly 


Shortly when Solution 3 calls the print() function, sometimes it returns a list.  So the function limit query reset. But For other solutions, they only call the print() function. So they get to limit of the queue.

Extra


By the way, if you increase the n limit from 10^4 to 10^5 or much more it will probably get an error.  Because in some values, it will call a lot of print() functions before resetting the query.
